# PowerShell modules update fails after replacing code signing certificate

Tags: powershell, code-signing, authenticode

We recently renewed our code signing certificate which I also use for signing PowerShell modules.
The original certificate was from VeriSign which was acquired by DigiCert and they are now the CA. This causes our PowerShell modules update to fail because the old modules and the new modules were signed by different root CAs:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Authenticode issuer 'CN=XXX, O=XXX, L=XXX, C=XXX' of the new module 'MODULE' with version '1.0.x' 
from root certificate authority 'CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US' is not matching with the authenticode issuer 'CN=XXX, O=XXX, L=XXX, C=XXX' of the previously-installed module 'MODULE' with version '1.0.y' from root certificate authority 'CN=VeriSign Class 3 
Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US'. If you still 
want to install or update, use -SkipPublisherCheck parameter.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.4\PSModule.psm1:9807 char:50
+ ... talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AuthenticodeIssuerMismatch,Validate-ModuleAuthenticodeSignature,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Anyone has any idea how this can be solved?